# Menu cd in C#.. bug !

Tags: .net, frameworks, autorun

I've made a menu for the install cd of our soft. It works only on 2 computers which has Visual Studio installed.

When I try it on others, which have just .Net framework installed, it just crashes...

Also, I wrote the short program in C#, and of course if .Net framework is not installed, I would like to launch 
the installation instead of the menu cd. Is there any way to do this with autorun file ?

Comment: might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

Comment: **Do you really think it can be considered a "bug" when you don't follow the instructions?**

.NET applications require the .NET Framework to be installed. Pretty simple requirement. They aren't going to run on customer's computers if they don't have the .NET Framework installed. You need to write the installer in unmanaged code, or include the .NET runtime on your distribution media.

Comment: I know that, actually that's why I'm here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reply to the part about the autorun file, I am guessing you must have used the publish feature of visual studio. I find your question confusing, but i think you want to load an installer off of the CD instead of loading your menu application(Correct me if i am wrong). To do that, you wull have to edit the AUTORUN.INF file. The standard format of this file is:

```
[autorun]
open=application.exe
icon=application.exe/application.ico
action=This will be shown when you right-click the icon in my computer
label=The label in my computer
```

replace application.exe with the path of your installer, and if you want a custom icon, put the path to the icon after icon=.
The action and label text both affect what is seen in 'My Computer'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm ok with the autorun for now. When I load the cd on my computer or my colleague one, it works (because we have Visual Studio). I did my own autorun file, and I would like to know if I can check if .Net is installed ?

Comment: You can use Dev-C++ to write a program that checks for dot net, and responds accordingly... Use the registry(I think dev-cpp supports that) The keys to look for can be found [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/check-version-dotnet-framework-installed-t1222779.html)

Comment: Not really, maybe directly with the .inf file.. But I think this time I will really need to go and work with C++...

Comment: No, you don't have to write the entire menu as c++, just a program that detects .net and if it is installed start the menu, otherwise start the .net installer.

Comment: ha ha... Yeah I didn't see it this way... I'll try.. Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome. If you liked my answer, feel free to set it as the accepted answer or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a native (read: C/C++) application that has no dependency on any installed library by statically linking to it. This application will check for the proper version of the .NET framework. If it is not installed, it will the start the installer. Otherwise, you can launch your application.